# compute $ \iint_De^{-x^2-4y^2} \ dxdy$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

The question is:
$$ \iint_De^{-x^2-4y^2} \ dxdy, \quad D=\{(x,y):0\leq x\leq2y\}$$
This is how i've tried to attack this but i was getting nowhere with it :
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-4y} \ dy \int_{0}^{2y}e^{-x^2}dx$$
Am i on the right path? how should i proceed

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The substitution $x=r\cos\theta,\,y=\tfrac12r\sin\theta$ of Jacobian $r/2$ writes the integral as$$\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}d\theta\int_0^\infty\tfrac12re^{-r^2}dr=\tfrac{\pi}{16}.$$

Comment: Can i ask you how did you find angles $\pi/4$ and $\pi/2$ ?

Comment: @simon Note $\tan\theta=2y/x\ge1$.

Comment: Sorry but what does it have to do with angles of integration? i don't get it

Comment: I also thought the same

Comment: @simon as far as the limits, please note that your original integral is over the line $x = 2y$ and with the substitution it would mean $\tan \theta = 1$.

Comment: @ Math Lover Thank you